# What is the relationship between information and degrees of freedom?

Tags: information-theory, classical-mechanics

When dealing with mathematical systems and transformations and such, you can often characterize a system by a certain number of "degrees of freedom", the smallest number of independent numbers needed to characterize it uniquely. If a transformation destroys a degree of freedom (eg a linear transformation with determinant $0$), it cannot be retrieved.

This seems to me to be very similar to information, where these is a minimum number of bits needed to describe a system, and mappings which remove bits will irretrievably lose information.

Are these two related? And how does this accord with things like Hilbert curves which seem to crush two degrees of freedom into one while still being bijective?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of degrees of freedom naturally arises in information theory. For example, consider the transmission of information via a channel whose effect can be modeled by the input-output relation

$$y = H x,$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the input (transmitted) "message", $H\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ is a matrix representing the channel effect/distortion and $y\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is the message observed at the receiver side. Clearly, if $H$ is of rank $1$ (i.e., one degree of freedom is available), the two elements of $x$ cannot be different, since they cannot be recovered. However, if $H$ is full rank (i.e., two degrees of freedom), then $x$ can have its two elements different, effectively doubling the information that is transmitted.

As we always target for increasing the amount of information, operating in channels with increased degrees of freedom becomes essential. This is, for example, why the bandwidth used by wireless communications systems is ever increasing, as the degrees of available degrees of freedom are proportional to its value.

However, note that information theory uses concepts such as entropy, and mutual information, which are more general than the degrees of freedom concept (and more appropriate for more sophisticated channel models than the previous example, e.g., taking into account random noise). Roughly, again considering the transmission problem, information theory will tell you how much information can be "carried" by each available degree of freedom in the presence of noise.

I am not familiar with Hilbert curves.

Comment: How does this relate to bits being discrete and d.o.f. being continuous? The analogy to me seems to be 1 dimension -> n bits, but of course dimensions (absent noise, which is not physically realizable) can encode infinite bits each. Is there a more general framework or common thread thinking the two concepts? And of course degrees of freedom are much much more general than linear transformations, that was just a concrete example.

Comment: @user6873235 What is the definition of (continuous) d.o.f.?

Comment: The definition of the degrees of freedom of a system is the size of the minimal set of numbers required to specify the state of the system, where those numbers are usually understood as real numbers.

Comment: @user6873235 So, does this mean that you allow for "minimal sets" to be uncoutable, with their "size" corresponding to some measure, therefore being, in general, non-integer? I am just asking out of curiosity, I am not familiar with this definition. Maybe you want to include this definition (or a reference) in your question as non-integer degrees of freedom are not considered (or even make sense) in *engineering* applications of information theory.

Comment: In this case we would consider the size to be the cardinality of the set, so if it were uncountably infinite (eg for a field), it would simply be uncountably infinite. Although the more practical examples to discuss would be cases of finite degrees.